# IPC between C# app, via native C++ DLL, to another app consuming DLL with embedded Lua?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, lua, ipc

Basically I'm asking how to implement the same flow as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978627/c-sharp-app-to-c-dll-back-to-the-c-sharp-app-via-callbacks).

I want my C# to supply callbacks to a native C++ DLL that I have written.

I want this DLL to be loaded by the Lua engine that's embedded into another application,
[MUSHClient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushclient) (a MUD/telnet client, with embedded Lua), via `package.loadlib("native.dll", "someInitFunction");`.

Then in [MUSHClient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushclient) I want to write scripts that call functions exposed by the DLL. I want these functions to call the callback function/delegate supplied by my C# application.

**How can I do this?** 

I know how to export functions in my DLL, what I don't know is how to share the callback between processes.

Comment: If you have two processes, you need some form of IPC. What sort of IPC do you want to use?

Comment: Is it possible to use shared memory and share a function pointer for the callback/delegate?

Comment: No it is not possible to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of Inter-process communication ([IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).

I'd recommend Named Pipes.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) is a good example of a named pipe implementation in C# & C++.

Comment: How do you use named pipes in native C++ (not C++/CLI)?

Comment: Eg. look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640642/c-implementing-named-pipes-using-the-win32-api)